# bash: clear string between two positions

Tags: shell-script, terminal, tput

I need to clear string in terminal between two positions (not the beginning or end of line). For example, delete all starting from `tput cup 5 10` and till `tput cup 5 69`. One line.

Yes, it's possible simply `echo` by spaces all this region, but, maybe, is there a better way? Something like `clear 10 69` on current cursor line position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the *erase character(s)* control sequence.

```
tput cup 5 10 ; tput ech 59
```

This is not to be confused with *delete character(s)*.

```
tput cup 5 10 ; tput dch 59
```

Erasure overwrites with blanks.  Deletion moves the rest of the line left.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, `ech` (*erase characters*) is the way to go—when it works.  That came in with VT102, so most terminals that you would use provide the feature.

For terminal descriptions from ncurses, there's an issue with color: rxvt's developer in 1995-1996 used a different interpretation of the idea on clearing background colors, and did not (as Linux console and xterm do) treat *erases* the same as *clearing*.  So `ech` clears with the default color, while `ed` (*erase display*) clears with the current ANSI color.  The ncurses terminal description omits `ech` for this reason.  The same issue applies to all of the programs derived from that source.

Further reading:

- [My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html)
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html), you would use `tput` with **`cup`** and **`ech`** capabilities:

```
       cursor_address            cup    cm   move to row #1 columns #2

       erase_chars               ech    ec   erase #1 characters (P)
```

- [**`tput`**,  **`reset`**  -  initialize  a  terminal or query terminfo
     database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use sed to do that, see the following

echo "string" | sed -e '/start/,/end/' | sed -e 's/pattern/replace/g'